# Passing file instance as parameter to a method with Object argument

Tags: groovy

I have a `setResultValue` method which accepts `Object` as argument

```
public class CommandResult {
  // other methods
  public void setResultValue(Object resultValue) {
        this.resultValue = resultValue;
    }
```

And am trying to pass a java.io.File instance file to this method as below

```
new CommandResult.setResultFile(file);
```

And am seeing the below error

```
 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.dc.core.behavior.command.model.impl.CommandResult.setResultFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File) values: 
Possible solutions: setResultValue(java.lang.Object), getResultValue()
```

Isnt the method `setResultFile` supposed to accept `file` since `Object` is the super class of all instances?

Comment: it's also `new CommandResult().set...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method signature is `setResultValue`. You call `setResultFile`.

Comment: Thanks, I havent noticed that its refactored